# Python. Iterating dictionary starting from certain key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "h": 55 }
```

Is there any way to iterate through the dictionary, starting from the "b" key?

Comment: What do you mean *"starting from"*? Dictionaries don't guarantee order, so that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: If you expect an order within the dictionary, look up [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered. It's in a random way that the keys and vals of a dict are displayed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dictionaries have *no order*; but if you expected alphabetical ordering you can sort the keys and skip until you get to the `'b'` key with [`itertools.dropwhile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile):

```
from itertools import dropwhile

for key in dropwhile(lambda k: k != 'b', sorted(your_dictionary)):
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "h": 55 }
>>> for key in dropwhile(lambda k: k != 'b', sorted(d)):
...     print key, d[key]
... 
b 2
h 55
```

Even if you were using a [`collections.OrderedDict()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) (which preserves insertion order), you'd still have to skip over the keys until you got to your 'starter' key.

Comment: Ok. I don't exprect alphabetical order in my solution (keys "a" and "b" are just for example) keys are words. But thanks anyway for showing this approach- I could use it i future)